# How to send mouse event to QVTKOpenGLWidget

Tags: qt, vtk

I am using `QVTKOpenGLWidget` for data visualization.
But sometimes all the actors are not drawn instantly after I added the actors to renderer, then calling `QVTKOpenGLWidget::update()`.
I don't know why this happens, and I cannot reproduce this issue.

However, I found once mouse drag event happened on `QVTKOpenGLWidget`, all the actors were drawn correctly. So I made an idea sending `QMouseMoveEvent` manually to `QVTKOpenGLWidget` by `QVTKOpenGLWidget::mouseEvent(&ev1)`. But nothing occurred While I could confirm by the event filter that the event was received.

My question is how I can send a mouse drag event just the same as the event driven by "actual" mouse in `QVTKOpenGLWidget`.

EDIT:2018-11-June

I fogot to call `vtkRendere::ResetCamera` after changing renderer's camera configuration. The problem is solved.

Comment: Can you show some simple (but complete) example from your code that does not work? How are you updating your objects that are not getting updated?

Comment: If you have set up your pipeline correctly then try doing something like `polyData->Modified()` where `polyData` is the input to the mapper before calling the `Render()`.

Comment: I made a minimum example. `qvtk->GetRenderWindow()->Render()` you mentioned solved everything in the example, and the absence of `Render` reproduced such a problem that I posted here. The essence of this problem is not Qt or VTK but that I cannot recognize the difference between my example and actual complex codes... I appreciate you.

Comment: FYI, QVTKOpenGLWidget have been rewrited in vtk master, you may want to try this one.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to explicitly pass a mouse event to force an update.
Suppose you have a `QVTKOpenGLWidget *qvtk` then in order to update the scene you should call `qvtk->GetRenderWindow()->Render()`.

Comment: Thanks Amit and Sivabalan. You are right. The reference document says so. `vtkRenderer::Render`, `qvtk->update`, or `qvtk->GetRenderWindow->Render()` should do. But in my case, sometimes `Renderer()` updates only the background precisely but no actor is drawn till mouse events. I can't found the reason. So I am trying the bogous workaround with emitting events. I know I maybe forget initializations or setting flags or something...